# How come my Discord bot (NodeJS) doesn't go online after a system reboot on a Raspberry Pi 4, with pm2?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, pm2, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to host a Discord bot on a Raspberry Pi. I have gotten everything to work and I have a bot running on it. I also made it so the bot restarts on a system reboot. The bot logs in perfectly. However, I tried adding another bot and again, I made it so the bot restarts on system reboot. The bot restarts from what I can see when I use `pm2 ls`. However, the bot doesn't go online. I get this error in my logs as well:

```
HTTPError [FetchError]: request to https://discord.com/api/v9/gateway/bot failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN discord.com
```

Also note that I *can* use `pm2 start <process>` and `node <file>` to start the bot. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is an error relative to DNS. It tell you that getaddrinfo is in timeout (or delayed?) and that you should try again later.

Not enough information to be more specific. But if you start these two bots at the same time, perharps your DNS or Discords DNS don't like that. Try to start  bots one after the other (with minutes betwens starts) and see if problem persist or not.

Comment: Even when I try it with *just* the bot that’s erroring, it give me the same error.